# Postgres - parsing text to array

Tags: postgresql

How to parse this input `text` to output `text[]` in PostgreSQL?
Input:

```
<foo>a</foo>
<foo>b</foo>
<foo>c</foo>
<foo>d</foo>
```

Expected output:

```
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
```

I tried using something like this, but it gives one extra element at the end. I'd like to not delete last element at the end this way. Is there a better solution?

```sql
SELECT STRING_TO_ARRAY(
    REPLACE('<foo>a</foo><foo>b</foo><foo>c</foo><foo>d</foo>', '<foo>', ''), 
    '</foo>')
```

Comment: 1) Not clear to me whether the `<foo>some_letter</foo>` are all one string to begin with or different records in a single column? 2) If you are looking for a Postgres array then the output would be `{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}`. What you are showing is a JSON array.

Comment: `<foo>some_letter</foo>`  are all one string and output is Postgres array.

Comment: you could remove the trailing </foo> before the String_to_Array

Comment: I should have been clearer, this `'<foo>a</foo><foo>b</foo><foo>c</foo><foo>d</foo>'` implies that the string is all in one field in one record. This `<foo>a</foo>`\n `<foo>b</foo>` ... says each `<foo>some_letter</foo` is in a different record for the given column. Which is it?

Comment: if you're not afraid of nested replaces, change </foo><foo> to a custom delimiter, remove <foo> and </foo>, and do string_to_array of the result with your custom delimiter

Answer (score 1):

The following processes the string and returns the field values as a `text[]`:

```
WITH t(test_value) AS (
  VALUES ('<foo>a</foo><foo>b</foo><foo>c</foo><foo>d</foo>')
)
SELECT XPATH('/root/foo/text()',
             ('<root>' || test_value || '</root>')::xml)::text[]
  FROM t;
```

The `<root>` wrapper is needed to make the string a well formed XML document as required by `XPATH`.